# highcharts-react-official useEffect

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, use-effect, react-highcharts

I'm trying create a simple area chart in react highcharts-react-official,

it is like this bellow https://codesandbox.io/s/volumechart-o8nrg.

But this link couldn't reproduce the problem.

The problem is Graph drawing is not stable.

It's mean some time  will be success but some time failure.

I checked console.log(props) all times stored correct data.

I think it maybe happen by browser because when I open chrome dev-tool then chart was output correct color and data.

and more also output correct color and data when I click some legends in chart's.

How can I debug this problem?

this was the success.
https://gyazo.com/e02eda013acd34cde8b78086e0ef577c

this was the failure.
https://gyazo.com/7add2f65b9610db550dc922d95ef2e62

The chart changed by select box
this is a sample I clicked select box. It chart Doesn't draw anything
https://gyazo.com/4330f12a6a2c2d9c8bfa496cd5de22fa

but when I clicked some legend, chart will draw contents.
this is a sample movie
https://gyazo.com/3cab5f69316cf4c932e0406ae1f95067
and it data is updated from clicked select box.

It mean data is correct and chart was reloaded.

but only can not output color and data.

other else success example are zoom or shrink browser size.

Comment: Hi @マットmatto, The problem can be related with data mutations. Please try to update the chart by a deep copy of your options. If that doesn't help, please reproduce the whole situation in codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ppotaczek.

I tried deep copy with lodash(npm package), like bellow
`import _ from 'lodash'`
`options={_.cloneDeep(options)}`

but did not resolve this problem.

Could you check this gif file again?
https://gyazo.com/ce0fd7a71522b1b071a67b272bf81af4

Comment: The series are drawn after zoom because the chart is redrawn. That point's out that probably somethig is wrong with data. Do you use async data? Does the example you added show exactly the same case as yours?

Comment: I Solved this problem with immutable option ` <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} immutable={true} />`
But I do not understand completely this option is what is going on. 
I used async data from useEffect fetch.

Comment: The `immutable` option causes that the chart to be recreated from scratch and not updated.